# Why Indexes are created faster when the table has PK? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table that materializes a SQL, it has 6 million records that is used only for SELECT operations.

I am creating a PK with a field that is the row number, creating this PK takes more than 5 minutes in some cases. Creating an index for this field other than PK takes less than 30 seconds.

When I create PK, the creation of other additional indexes (unrelated to the PK field) is about 1/3 of the time when I don't create PK (but create an index for the PK field).

Why is this time difference?

```
Creating table (inserts): 262 sec
Creating index A (without PK constraint): 9 sec
Creating index C: 32 sec
Creating index D: 42 sec
Creating index E: 20 sec
Creating index F: 59 sec
Creating index G: 26 sec
Creating index H: 24 sec
Creating index I: 23 sec
Creating index J: 22 sec


Creating table (inserts): 135 sec
Creating index A (with PK constraint): 556 sec
Creating index C: 21 sec
Creating index D: 11 sec
Creating index E: 12 sec
Creating index F: 22 sec
Creating index G: 11 sec
Creating index H: 11 sec
Creating index I: 11 sec
Creating index J: 10 sec
```

Additional indexes are from a single field, either text or date.

Analyzing these scenarios it seems better to create PK (even not using it in SQL) because if you create more indexes will be faster even though the creation of PK is much slower, but I did not understand why.

Comment: Indices often use multiple levels of indirection, some of which may use the PK, to match data.

Comment: imagine a book without a reference/chapters (PK) how fast do you think you can create the table of contents (index)?

Comment: It was related to the fact that PK was CLUSTERED and not because it was PK only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not the primary key.  It is the fact that the primary key is clustered (by default).  The increase in speed is likely due to the fact that the clustered (i.e. primary) key is significantly smaller than the alternative, which is a *row locator*.

Much of index creation is moving data around (sorting by the keys and saving the results on index pages).

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-index-design-guide?view=sql-server-ver15) explains:

> The row locators in nonclustered index rows are either a pointer to a
>   row or are a clustered index key for a row, as described in the
>   following:
>
> - If the table is a heap, which means it does not have a clustered
>     index, the row locator is a pointer to the row. The pointer is built
>     from the file identifier (ID), page number, and number of the row on
>     the page. The whole pointer is known as a Row ID (RID).
> - If the table has a clustered index, or the index is on an indexed
>     view, the row locator is the clustered index key for the row.

I am guessing that the indexes with the largest increase in speed have the smallest keys.  Conversely, if your primary key were a GUID -- which I'm guessing is wider than a row location but I don't know for sure -- then the index creation might be slower.

Comment: Is it fair to say that a clustered index also performs data reordering and that will take a while for 6 million records whereas nonclustered indexes are building new data structures.

Comment: That's right, I did a test creating the index as the CLUSTERED option and the result was similar to what was obtained with the creation of PK.